# Unable to resolve "./removed" from "node_modules\expo\build\ExpoLazy.js"

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm facing this error when I scanned my phone with QR Code and app runs. If anyone who faced this issue or have a solution so please let me know the solutions for it.
Thanks

> Unable to resolve "./removed" from
>   "node_modules\expo\build\ExpoLazy.js"

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import TrackListScreen from './src/screens/TrackListScreen';
import TrackDetailScreen from './src/screens/TrackDetailScreen';
import TrackCreateScreen from './src/screens/TrackCreateScreen';
import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';


const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    trackListFlow: createStackNavigator({
      TrackList: TrackListScreen,
      TrackDetail: TrackDetailScreen
    }),
    TrackCreate: TrackCreateScreen,
    Account: AccountScreen
  })
});

export default createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
```

Comment: Did you try to clean npm cache as `npm cache clean -f`?

Answer (score 1):

run expo r -c to clear the expo cache as well as npm cache clean -f

got the answer from here
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5769